# Binary filestream to byte std::vector skips spaces

Tags: c++, file, c++11, visual-studio-2012, vector

When I use this code

```
std::string filename = "tmp.bin";
std::ifstream fileStream;
std::vector<unsigned char> fileBuffer;

fileStream = std::ifstream(filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);     
fileBuffer.reserve(fileStream.tellg());
fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
fileBuffer.insert(fileBuffer.begin(), std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(fileStream), std::istream_iterator<BYTE>());
```

all original spaces in my binary file are skipped -> fileBuffer contains no spaces, but need all tokens for Base64 encoding.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`, `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>` to extract data, which for `char` and `unsigned char` will skip whitespace by default.

Side note: filebufs in C++ are defined in terms of the C standard, which has the following to say in a note regarding seeking to the end of binary files:

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

It'll probably work fine regardless, but unless the reallocations are a serious issue you should just one-shot the file

```
std::ifstream fileStream("tmp.bin", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileBuffer{
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream), 
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
};
```

Older C++ will need to avoid a vexing parse with

```
std::vector<char> fileBuffer(
  (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream)),
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

If your library has `char_traits` for `unsigned char` you could also use `std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char>` although this isn't portable, you can always convert to `unsigned char` later anyway depending on what you need.

Comment: Something weird happened -> I can't access fileBuffer if I do it like this! Maybe its very simple, but Visual Studio shows error "Error: expression must have class type"! (iterator is included) WTF???

Comment: @leon22 can you post a short example somewhere?

Comment: @leon22 Whoops, most vexing parse, fixed now, assuming you can use c++11.

Comment: I use VS2012 (C++-11), so this code does not compile! Sorry in this special case it seems there is a difference between C++-11 and C++-14. Could you please update it again? Thx

Comment: @leon22 I've added a non-C++11 version.

Comment: Thx. Now it works. It seems VS2012 have here not the full C++-11 support!